# Does spreading a bite effect at the colony affect helpless survivors?

Tags: dead-of-winter

Does spreading the bite effect end at the colony if the last player survivor dies, or does it spread to helpless survivors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Helpless survivors are not affected by the spreading of a bite effect.

Bite effects spread to the character with the lowest influence first. Helpless survivors do not have any stats (If they did, I would assume that they would have the lowest influence out of all the survivors).

The exact wording in the rules (page 11) is as follows:

> Roll the exposure die again. On a blank result, the survivor that the
>   bite effect spread to is not killed and the bite effect stops
>   spreading. On any other result, the survivor that the bite effect
>   spread to is killed and the bite effect spreads again. The bite effect
>   will continue to spread until a player either chooses option 1, rolls
>   a blank result after choosing option 2, or there are no more survivors
>   at the location.

Comment: One thing that threw me was whether mention of 'survivor' in the manual referred to both the non-helpless and helpless survivors. One would think, language wise, it typically would, but, as you mentioned, they have no stats and there is no explanation of how one would even go about making the decision to make decisions for those npc's.